# Android google maps navigation without Intent

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, google-maps-android-api-2, currentlocation

I tried navigation with Intents when user click on marker and it's work well. Problem is that I need implement that in my own app. (without opening GoogleMaps app)
How to start implement navigation from current location to markers in my own app without intents? Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Find somebody who offers a navigation library, then add it to your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for fast reply

Answer (score 0):

You may use [this](https://github.com/tyczj/MapNavigator) library. It uses Directions API but in free plan it has limit to 2500 requests/day.

Comment: Thak you @deepankar. I just looked trought code and that could be it. My question is can I add this library to gradle, in dependencies or I need to add whole code.

Comment: @ZinjkaGlavinja I don't think this library is pushed to jcenter or maven. You will need to clone this repository and import it as module into your app.